# How can fetched records from phpmyadmin db falls within the four columns in a page before breaking into the next page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a table that fetches records from a db table into html page of four columns. I've been able to do this. However, the challenge i have now is that the records fetched break into different pages without covering the four columns. My question is how can the records falls within the four columns before breaking into the next page as shown in this picture [fig.1 sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqsdc.jpg)

```
**here is my codes**

  **CSS**


    <head>
       <title>Fastest & Secured Recharge Card</title>

       <style>
    .newspaper {
        -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-gap: 10px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-gap: 10px; /* Firefox */
        column-gap: 10px;
    }


    body {
      background: rgb(204,204,204); 
    }
    page {
      background: white;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    }
    page[size="A4"] {  
      width: 21cm;
      height: 2.8cm; 
    }


    @media print {
      body, page {
        margin: 0;
        box-shadow: 0;
      }
    }


    @media all {
        .page-break {  display: block; page-break-before: auto;}
    }

    @media print {
        .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: auto; }
    }

    p {
        margin: 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm;
    }



    .newspaper {
        -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-gap: 10px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-gap: 5px; /* Firefox */
        column-gap: 2px;
    }


    p {
        margin: 0.1cm 0.1cm 0.5cm 0.3cm;
    }


    </style>
    enter code here
    enter code here

   </head>
```

**HTML**

```
   <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
<page size="A4">




<div class="newspaper"><p>


    <TABLE cellpadding="0" style="font-family: Times New Roman" border="0"> 

            <tr>


         <td align="left" style="font-size:12px"><strong>



         <?php echo $line['agent'];?> &nbsp;&nbsp; &#8358;<?php echo $line['denom'];?> </strong></td></tr>
         <tr><td style="font-size:12px" ><i>Ref: &nbsp;<?php echo $line['agent'];?>-<?php echo $line['refno'];?></i><img align="left" src="images/airtel.png" alt="" style="width:35px;height:23px;"></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>

            <td style="font-size:12px">S/NO.:&nbsp;<?php echo $line['sn'];?></td>

            </tr>
            <td style="font-size:13px"><strong>PIN:&nbsp;<?php echo $line['povo'];?>&nbsp;-<?php echo $line['pive'];?>&nbsp;-<?php echo $line['perha'];?>&nbsp;-<?php echo $line['pene'];?></strong></td>
            </tr> 

            <tr><td style="font-size:12px"><i>Date: <?php echo $line['dt'];?> </i></td></tr>


    </TABLE></p>
</div><page></body>
```

Comment: I  have seen this type of of coding 7 or 8 years back. Ok, there is no picture attached as mentioned in your question.

Comment: You want to implement pagination on `php`, that's pretty easy, here is a step by step guide http://www.onlinetuting.com/pagination-in-php-mysqli/   . Just for the record, the `mysql_` extension has been deprecated...try using `mysqli` or `PDO`, and also be careful with `sql injection`.